# Tidying messy coordinates for use in measurements

Tags: r, regex, distance, units-of-measurement, geosphere

I have some rather messy degrees, decimal minutes coordinates (the source of which is out of my control) in the following format (see below). I am trying to work out the distance between the points ultimately.

```
minlat <- "51  12.93257'"
maxlat <- "66  13.20549'"
minlong <- "- 5   1.23944'"
maxlong <- "- 5   1.36293'"
```

As they are they are in a rather unfriendly format for (from `measurements` package):

```
measurements::conv_unit(minlat, from = 'deg_dec_min', to = 'dec_deg')
```

and ultimately

```
distm(c(minlong, minlat), c(maxlong, maxlat), fun = distHaversine)
```

I think I need to use the gsub( to get them into a friendly format, whereby I would like them to be

```
minlat <- 51 12.93257 # removing the double space
minlong <- -4 1.36293 # removing the double space and the space after the -
```

I've been messing around with gusb( all morning and it has beaten me, any help would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to strip all excess whitespace.  We can try using `gsub` with lookarounds here.

```
minlong <- " - 5   1.23944 "   # -5 1.23944
minlong
gsub("(?<=^|\\D) | (?=$|\\D)", "", gsub("\\s+", " ", minlong), perl=TRUE)

[1] " - 5   1.23944 "
[1] "-5 1.23944"
```

The inner call to `gsub` replaces any occurence of two or more spaces with just a single space.  The outer call then selectively removes a remaining single space *only* if it not be sandwiched between two digits.

Comment: Great that worked a treat for the longs, but the double space remains in the lats, how would one go about keeping one space while removing the additional?
Many thanks, I find regex very confusing

Comment: Ah no worries, thanks for your help! Much appreciated

Comment: @Jim I fixed it, but I had to make two calls to `gsub`.  I failed to do it one regex.

Comment: Brilliant @Tim! That's great, any solution is great with gsub(. Thanks for your continued support!